# PHP: how to access the data members of super class in subclass with the same name?

Tags: php, inheritance

I searched everywhere but did not find any solution to this question.
 Following is my code where I want to access the `$myvar` of the super class in the subclass but I don't know how? when I use `$this` keyword it accesses the variable in the same class but not the one in super class. please any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php 


class First{
    protected $myvar = "First Class";
}


class Second extends First{

    public $myvar = "Second Class";

    function __construct(){
        echo $this -> myvar;// here I want to access the $myvar of super class
    }

} 

$obj = new Second();

 ?>
```

**Note: I can achieve the same functionality in java by using the `super` keyword.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't you are overwritten in when creating the sub class which inherits from the parent class. So you would have to change the name for it.

Comment: But it can be done in java by using super keyword but why not here?

Comment: @khan In php the child sees automatically all public and protected properties and methods from the parent class. If you overwrite it in the child class as I said then you *overwrite* it so you can't access the parent property anymore

Comment: @khan A workaround for/in php would be if you declare the properties static, then you can use `self` and `parent` to access both of them

Answer (score 2):

The way you try to do this will not work, as Rizier mentioned. Maybe static properties can be useful to you (depending on your needs ofcourse)

```
<?php
class a {
    protected static $var = 'a';
}

class b extends a {
    protected static $var = 'b';

    public function __construct() {
        echo self::$var;
        echo parent::$var;

    }
}

$b = new b();
```

You could also reconstruct `a` in `b`. You'd be able to leverage the inheritance for methods and maybe other properties, while being able to use the default value in `a`-constructor.

```
<?php
class a {
    protected  $var = 'a';
}

class b extends a {
    protected  $var = 'b';

    public function __construct() {
        echo $this->var;

        $a = new a();
        echo $a->var;

    }
}

$b = new b();
```

The main question I think you should answer is why you want a class to inherit from another but still want to be able to change/modify stuff in the parent. That's kinda counterproductive for the whole inheritance design.

Answer (score 2):

You may create a custom function that returns the variables from the parent class BUT keep in mind that the variables should be "private":

```
class First{
    private $myvar = "First Class";
    protected function get_variable($var_name)
    {
        return $this->{$var_name};
    }
}
class Second extends First{
    public $myvar = "Second Class";
    function __construct() {
        echo parent::get_variable('myvar');
    }

}
$obj = new Second();
```

Answer (score 1):

You override the parent parameter with:
public $myvar = "Second Class";
Remove this line to use the inherits from parent class or change the name of the child class parameter.